# how to restrict user to save images from site not by disabling right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento, ftp

how to restrict user to save images from site not by disabling right click.

I tried disabling right click but it is causing problem for image with link, as we unable to right click on that image to open a lick in a new tab.

Any other good solution or advise??

Comment: You cannot prevent people from downloading images you make available for your website. It is simply not possible.

Comment: concept of disabling right click for this purpose died years ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of images with water mark of your site.

If a user can see the image on screen you can not restrict the user form saving the image.

1) user can use print screen option.

2)user can save the page with complete html option.this way she/he will get image.

3)user can take the snapshot of image if it is visible in forntend to the user.

Answer (score 4):

If the end user can see the image, it's already on his system. Saving it to a system or copying it to the clipboard is trivial and cannot be disabled in any reliable way.

If you want to keep control over the image, don't put it on the internet.

Watermarking is the best solutionyou can do.

Whatever your solution, in the end user can take a screen shot anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to serve images with your logo or string identifying your property so that it renders the image useless unless they are OK using it as is. However you can't prevent the saving of what is served. Another option is to serve only thumbnails or lower quality version of it.
Stay away from disabling normal user actions, like right-click disabling.